# AWS Elastic Beanstalk symfony console command not working in EB configuration file

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My `symfony.config` file contains the following `container_command`:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

`php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` works fine through `ssh` (with `sudo`), but when I deploy the app via `git aws.push` I get the following error:

```
[Instance: i-0123456789 Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null]
    Failed on instance with return code: 1 Output: Error occurred during build:
    Command 01_schemaupdate failed .
```

The only thing I can think of is permissions, but I thought that the config commands are run as the `webapp` user. Adding `sudo` doesn't help either. Any ideas?

Comment: Are sure that your command have all necessary configuration in order to connect to db? How many instances do you have?

Comment: Single instance. DB connection is working. Command works via ssh, the Symfony app itself is working.

Comment: Do you have another Configuration File which contained a command named 01_schemaupdate?

The command defined in symfony.config is named 01_migrate.